# How to convert date format in SPARQL?

Tags: date, sparql

I am new to SPARQL and searched the web for quite some time now. My endpoint is http://dbpedia.org/sparql and I am using http://yasgui.laurensrietveld.nl/ to execute the queries.

I can retrieve the date which looks like 1994-04-11 00:00:00. Now for display purpose, I need to show the date as MM/DD/yyyy format i.e. 4/11/1994. Is there any function which will help me ?

I dont want to use STR , CONCAT ,YEAR, MONTH, DAY functions since I want the query results to be sorted by earliest date.

EDIT: My query has  group by ?name order by ?date. I want to get the earliest date. e.g. for "abc", I have three dates, 10/13/2001; 10/15/2007 and 10/22/2007. I want to get the earliest date 10/13/2001.

Comment: You can use the functions `STR`, `CONCAT`, `MONTH` etc while still sorting by date.

Comment: I am not clear on what exactly you're asking after your latest edit. Your original question was about converting dates to a different format, but now you seem to be asking about grouping and sorting instead. Perhaps you should show your entire query and specify more precisely what it is that you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming the date values in DBPedia you are selecting are valid `xsd:dateTime` strings (the string you have in your question is not valid), you can easily do this as follows:

```
   SELECT ?x (CONCAT(STR(MONTH(?date)), 
                     "/", 
                     STR(DAY(?date)), 
                     "/", 
                    STR(YEAR(?date))) as ?displayDate)
   WHERE {
              ?x :hasDate ?date.
   }
   ORDER BY ?date
```

Comment: Thanks Jeen, I just updated my question. I missed the earliest date from a group part.